# member function template with Paradigm C++ compiler

Tags: c++, templates

I want to port a C++ program the utilizes member function templates to the rather old **Paradigm C++** compiler. The same code compiles fine with Microsoft compilers:

```
struct Foo
{
    int counter;
};

class A
{
public:
    template<class T> T* Successor(T*t) { return (t + 1); } // <<-----
};

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    A a;
    a.Successor(&foo);
}
```

The line with the template is honored with this error message:

> sample.cpp(15,33):Declaration terminated incorrectly.

Is there any other variant to define a member function template?

*edit:*
The compiler issues the same error message if only the member function's prototype is in the class definition. So moving the function body doesn't help.

Comment: Putting the definition outside the class doesn't help?

Comment: Well, it should be a member function. So the function prototype must not be moved. Moving the implementation out of the class definition doesn't help.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Can't reproduce the problem with GCC 4.4.7.

Comment: @ThomasSablik The question says "paradigm". I don't know it, and I can't find an appropriate tag for it.

Comment: I see. For a record - function's definition is the function's implementation (with braces) also called a body. Prototype is declaration.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I emphasized the compiler's name now.

Comment: @cigien Didn't consider this could be a compiler name

Comment: You should upgrade your compiler/toolchain. Looks like support for [paradigm](https://devtools.com/) has ended.

Comment: @cigien I am aware of the end of support by Paradigm. So an upgrade is even harder. But currently I have to stick with the old thing, it's not just for fun.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. I was just suggesting that you upgrade *if* possible.

Comment: The problem with this compiler is that it doesn't follow the C++ standard. It's not able to compile valid code. This is not a C++ question but a very compiler specific question. That means you can either try different approaches or read the documentation.